# Powershell Format-Table: Logically breaking long strings

Tags: powershell

I'm having a problem with the output of `format-table`. I'm not sure if there's a way to do this, but it's worth asking...

I'm going to just dive in and define what I'm working with right now on a stripped-down level.

> $find = read-host "what do you want to find?"
>
> $file = read-host "Where do you want to look?"
>
> $format = @{expression={$*.linenumber};label="Line";width=5},@{expression={$*.line};label="Data"
>
> $result = select-string -simple $find $file | select LineNumber,Line | format-table $format -auto -wrap | foreach-object {$_; echo ""}
>
> $result

The end result is pretty simple, it makes a two-column table with a small "line" column and a larger column for the data on that line.

There's one issue: the Data column breaks at a character length, which makes it bad for reading or output to file. An example would be as follows:

```
Line Data                                                                        
---- ----                                                                        

  17 <div role="note">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Se
     d sit amet varius leo, vel adipiscing lacus. Ut pharetra tristique mauris id
      pulvinar. Nunc dictum volutpat eros, ut mattis purus ultrices vehicula. Mor
     bi non rhoncus tortor, in pulvinar tortor.
```

As you can see, "sed" and "Morbi" are cut at the line end.  It'd be nice if it cut in such a way where it identified spaces and dropped to the next line.  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** *The solution marked as correct was marked as such because it is probably the closest thing to ideal.  If a better alternative shows up, that will likely become the solution.  I simply used it and it worked well enough.*

Comment: I don't think you're going to get it to do that.  It just does simple width formatting, so it's lightweight and fast.  If they made it do things like text editor style fomatting it would start getting big and slow.

Comment: Agreed with @mjolinor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try piping it to Out-String with a large -Width?

Comment: I hadn't until you suggested it. Static large widths are doing the same thing, just in different places (did with 500, but not with 1000, as the lines aren't that long).

I may have to get the length of the string it finds, assign a variable to that length, and call it for the -width flag if nothing else.  It seems like undue complication, but the flexibility may be worth it in the long run.

Comment: In hindsight, large widths don't help when in console, only when dumping to file.